# rivets.js each-* not displaying

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript, rivets.js

I'm trying to use rivets.js (via `rivets-rails` gem) to bind an array of straight JavaScript objects (no JS model library like Backbone etc), which are retrieved via JSON api in a Rails app.

The element to bind to (first HAML, then output):

```
%tr(rv-each-function="functions")
  %td { function.name }

<tr rv-each-function="functions">
  <td>{ function.name }</td>
</tr>
```

Binding code (CoffeeScript):

```
functions_table = rivets.bind $("#functions_table"), {functions: AdminData.Functions}
```

`AdminData.Functions` looks like this (via JSON.stringify):

```
[{"id":1,"name":"SomeData"},{"id":2,"name":"OtherData"},{"id":3,"name":"YetMoreData"}]
```

When I inspect the rivets View `functions_table` via `console.log`, I see that `tbody#functions_table` is the sole member of `functions_table.els` and that `functions_table.models.functions` contains the expected Array of objects, yet the data isn't being bound, so the output in the page is just `{ function.name }`, as shown in the first code block.

The rivets documentation is a bit inconsistent - the description shows that one should use `data-item-*` yet the example shows `rv-item-*` (see [Usage Iteration](http://www.rivetsjs.com/docs/#usage-iteration) in rivets docs). I've tried both.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: FIXED: The `rivets-rails` gem is apparently out-of-date, and using an older version of rivets.js which doesn't support binding to plain JS objects. Switching to using the current rivets.min.js made my code work as-is.